# Wrong Format of the initialization string in ADO.NET

Tags: wpf, parameters, ado.net

I just have a simply method show below:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string sqlcmdString = string.Format("UPDATE Bills SET Name = '@name', Time = '@time', Product = '@pro', Price = @money WHERE Name = '@value';");

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlcmdString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Bills", con))
        {
            // tell ADO.NET it's a stored procedure (not inline SQL statements)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // define parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tb_TenKH.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cb_Thoigian.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pro", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tb_SanPham.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@money", SqlDbType.Money).Value = tb_ThanhTien.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = cellvalue;

            // open connection, execute stored procedure, close connection again
            con.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                //dosomething
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed!!!");
            }
            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

This lines could not be run. When i debug it, it shows error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does
>   not conform to specification starting at index 0.'

I aware that something went wrong in my `sqlcmdString` maybe about syntax, but I couldn't determine it. Please give me a help.

Comment: `SqlConnection` expects a connection string as parameter, not an update query. The update belongs inside `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Where are you passing the SP name ?? "dbo.Bills" doesn't look like SP name. Refer this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834249/execute-stored-procedure-from-wpf

Comment: @diiN__________ so what can I do to handle it? I'm so stuck...

Comment: @NareshRavlani I am not pass any SP, "dbo.Bills" is the name of table I want to update in DB. is is wrong syntax? Please help me.

Comment: @PhanThếKhương : As you have mentioned CommandType 
 as a StoredProcedure, I believe you want to work with SP here. When you are working with SP, you do not have to pass query and table name from C# code. Instead, you have to pass the name of SP and parameters for the SP. In my previous comment, I have shared a link, please refer to it and let me know if you need any more help with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrong in syntax: I should use like below:

```
string sqlcmdString = string.Format("UPDATE Bills SET Name = '@name', Time = '@time', Product = '@pro', Price = @money WHERE Name = '@value';");

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                // define parameters
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tb_TenKH.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cb_Thoigian.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pro", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = tb_SanPham.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@money", SqlDbType.Money).Value = tb_ThanhTien.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = cellvalue;

                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thành Công!!!");
                    if (passrow != null)
                    {
                        string[] result_back = { tb_TenKH.Text, cb_Thoigian.Text, tb_SanPham.Text, tb_ThanhTien.Text };
                        passrow(result_back);
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thất Bại!!!");
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why still using parameters? You can replace @name with tb_TenKH.Text and so on..in sqlcmdString itself.